# Unable to install moviepy

Tags: python, ffmpeg

First I typed the following commands in the terminal to install the necessary packages:

```
pip install moviepy
pip install ffmpeg
```

Then when I tried to run the following code, I got this:

```
from moviepy.editor import *
```

Error: RuntimeError: No ffmpeg exe could be found. Install ffmpeg on your system, or set the IMAGEIO_FFMPEG_EXE environment variable.

To fix the error, I typed the following code above the previous line of code:

```
import os
os.environ["IMAGEIO_FFMPEG_EXE"] = "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/ffmpeg"
from moviepy.editor import *
```

This fixed the issue I was having earlier and I was able to import it. The location you see typed in the code was directly copied from the output from the location attribute when I typed **pip show ffmpeg** in the terminal.
However, when I actually try and use the library, I get errors:

```
import os
os.environ["IMAGEIO_FFMPEG_EXE"] = "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/ffmpeg"
from moviepy.editor import *

clip = VideoFileClip("master_video.mp4")
```

```
Error: 
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
PermissionError                           Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [2], in <cell line: 5>()
      2 os.environ["IMAGEIO_FFMPEG_EXE"] = "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/ffmpeg"
      3 from moviepy.editor import *
----> 5 clip = VideoFileClip("master_video.mp4") 
      7 for x in range(0,10):
      8     print(randint(0, 2420))

File /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/moviepy/video/io/VideoFileClip.py:88, in VideoFileClip.__init__(self, filename, has_mask, audio, audio_buffersize, target_resolution, resize_algorithm, audio_fps, audio_nbytes, verbose, fps_source)
     86 # Make a reader
     87 pix_fmt = "rgba" if has_mask else "rgb24"
---> 88 self.reader = FFMPEG_VideoReader(filename, pix_fmt=pix_fmt,
     89                                  target_resolution=target_resolution,
     90                                  resize_algo=resize_algorithm,
     91                                  fps_source=fps_source)
     93 # Make some of the reader's attributes accessible from the clip
     94 self.duration = self.reader.duration

File /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/moviepy/video/io/ffmpeg_reader.py:35, in FFMPEG_VideoReader.__init__(self, filename, print_infos, bufsize, pix_fmt, check_duration, target_resolution, resize_algo, fps_source)
     33 self.filename = filename
     34 self.proc = None
---> 35 infos = ffmpeg_parse_infos(filename, print_infos, check_duration,
     36                            fps_source)
     37 self.fps = infos['video_fps']
     38 self.size = infos['video_size']

File /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/moviepy/video/io/ffmpeg_reader.py:257, in ffmpeg_parse_infos(filename, print_infos, check_duration, fps_source)
    254 if os.name == "nt":
    255     popen_params["creationflags"] = 0x08000000
--> 257 proc = sp.Popen(cmd, **popen_params)
    258 (output, error) = proc.communicate()
    259 infos = error.decode('utf8')

File /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/subprocess.py:969, in Popen.__init__(self, args, bufsize, executable, stdin, stdout, stderr, preexec_fn, close_fds, shell, cwd, env, universal_newlines, startupinfo, creationflags, restore_signals, start_new_session, pass_fds, user, group, extra_groups, encoding, errors, text, umask, pipesize)
    965         if self.text_mode:
    966             self.stderr = io.TextIOWrapper(self.stderr,
    967                     encoding=encoding, errors=errors)
--> 969     self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,
    970                         pass_fds, cwd, env,
    971                         startupinfo, creationflags, shell,
    972                         p2cread, p2cwrite,
    973                         c2pread, c2pwrite,
    974                         errread, errwrite,
    975                         restore_signals,
    976                         gid, gids, uid, umask,
    977                         start_new_session)
    978 except:
    979     # Cleanup if the child failed starting.
    980     for f in filter(None, (self.stdin, self.stdout, self.stderr)):

File /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/subprocess.py:1845, in Popen._execute_child(self, args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds, pass_fds, cwd, env, startupinfo, creationflags, shell, p2cread, p2cwrite, c2pread, c2pwrite, errread, errwrite, restore_signals, gid, gids, uid, umask, start_new_session)
   1843     if errno_num != 0:
   1844         err_msg = os.strerror(errno_num)
-> 1845     raise child_exception_type(errno_num, err_msg, err_filename)
   1846 raise child_exception_type(err_msg)

PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/ffmpeg'
```

Thank you so much in advance

Comment: is the video file opened? or other process trying to access it? when you are running the code?

Answer (score 0):

It seems as though there is no easy way to use ffmpeg in python, so I would recommend you install a package such as [ffmpeg-python](https://github.com/kkroening/ffmpeg-python) instead. If you are insistent on using ffmpeg, follow the workarounds mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48811312/install-ffmpeg-in-to-virtual-environment#:%7E:text=Go%20and%20download%20the%20ffmpeg%20package%20you%20desire,you%20won%27t%20get%20the%20error%20message%20you%20described.) though. This avoids your second issue, which arises from setting the environment path to a folder and then try to open a file